# Typescript method decorator : this is undefined

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'am trying to play a little with typescript decorators, as stated in the question in a method decorator the this is not set to anything (undefined).

in the code below I am trying to make a controller decorator that will create a koa-router on the controller class. the method decorator will wrap the method and call it with koa context.

index.ts:

```
import koa, { ParameterizedContext } from "koa";
import koarouter from "koa-router";

const app = new koa();

function Controller<T extends new (...args: any[]) => {}>(path: string) {
  return (controller: T) => {
    const router = new koarouter({ prefix: path });
    if (controller.prototype.routes) {
      const routes = controller.prototype.routes;
      Object.entries(routes).forEach((e) => {
        if (e[0] === "GET") {
          Object.entries(e[1]).forEach((r) => {
            router.get(r[0], r[1]);
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return class extends controller {
      public router: koarouter = router;
    };
  };
}

function HttpGet(path: string): MethodDecorator {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
  return function(
    target: any,
    propertyName: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
  ) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]): any {
      return originalMethod(...args);
    };
    if (!target.routes) {
      target.routes = { GET: {}, POST: {} };
    }
    target.routes.GET = { ...target.routes.GET, [path]: descriptor.value };
    return descriptor;
  };
}

// tslint:disable-next-line: max-classes-per-file
@Controller("/adex")
class AdexController {
  constructor(private msg: string = "") {
    this.allAdexs = this.allAdexs.bind(this);
  }
  @HttpGet("/id")
  public allAdexs(ctx: ParameterizedContext) {
    console.log(this);
    ctx.body = `hi from adex ${this.msg}`;
  }
}

const adexController = new AdexController();

app.use(adexController.router.routes());
app.use(adexController.router.allowedMethods());

app.listen(3000);
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2015" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "declaration": true /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */,
    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    "outDir": "./lib" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */,
    "strict": false /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "baseUrl": "./" /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

Comment: You should reduce the code significantly. Chop off the irrelevant things so that we can easier see where's the real problem.

Comment: i resolved my problem, i will soon enough write a detailed description of the problem and the solution.

Comment: @Houss_gc, what was your solution? Answer your own question for the sake of the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is not really true. If you define a function within the decorator and assign that to the `descriptor.value`, it will be bound to `this` when called:

```
export function someDecorator() {
    return function (
        object: Object, propertyName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ): void {
        const originalFunction = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function () {
            // here you have access to `this`:
            return originalFunction.bind(this)();
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem in my code is a classic this problem in JavaScript, I am using a class method outside a class and trying to access this. this problem can't be solved what I was trying to do is simply impossible, in order to construct a koa-router I need a controller instance and the methods on this instance need to be bound to this instance, which is impossible in a class or method decorator, when the decorator code is run we don't have instances yet.
I change the design from trying to construct the router in the decorator to delegate this task to another class that will do it at run time and let the decorators only annotate the classes.